# Weird output when parsing special characters using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a french website but the french langage have some special characters like `é` and `à` etc and I end up with some weird output for exemple instead of that (Inspect in Google Chrome)

```
<a href="www.exemple.com/1" title="Soins Anti-âge et Anti-rides">
  <span>Soins Anti-âge et Anti-rides</span>
</a>

<a href="www.exemple.com/2" title="Rides installées">
  <span>Rides installées</span>
</a>
```

I will get this output (Text Visualizer in Visual Studio)

```
<a href="www.exemple.com/1" title="Soins Anti-&acirc;ge et Anti-rides">
  <span>Soins Anti-&acirc;ge et Anti-rides</span>
</a>

<a href="www.exemple.com/2" title="Rides install&eacute;es">
  <span>Rides install&eacute;es</span>
</a>
```

My code is the following

```
string url = "https://universparadiscount.ma/7-product.html";
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
string html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

string SubCategory = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("span")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("itemprop", string.Empty)
    .Equals("title")).LastOrDefault()?.InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t', ' ');
Console.WriteLine(SubCategory);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the problem, you can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0)

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission
> into a decoded string.
>
> To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the
> `WebUtility` class.

**Example**

```
Console.WriteLine(SubCategory);
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(SubCategory));
```

**Output**

```
Rides install&eacute;es
Rides installées
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I used `htmlDocument.LoadHtml(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html));`

Comment: @Yox just be careful with that, using it before hand is likely to break your html structure. Better to use it afterwards on the text you need